# Lightning bolt for prompt (PS1)

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, terminal, prompt

I've seen on a few screencasts a while back where someone had a lightning bolt instead of `$` on the bash prompt.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This page](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html) explains how to set your bash promt. As @ulidtko says, you can use `⚡` as one example of a lightning bolt symbol. To set this, use:

```
export PS1=⚡
```

You will, however, lose everything else in the prompt you had before (not just the $). What you had before depends on your distribution. On my Ubuntu 10.10 setup it's `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$` by default, which you can get by running `echo $PS1`. To use mine as an example, to just change the `$` to a `⚡`, run:

```
export PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w⚡ "
```

To make this change across all bash shells, add the above line to your `~/.bashrc` file.

The result is like this:

```
marcog@minime:~⚡ echo hello world
hello world
```

Answer (score 5):

Ignacio's answer is right, but here is another symbol, which in my font looks better:

#### `U+26A1 HIGH VOLTAGE SIGN` (`⚡`)

Answer (score -1):

There are a few lightning-bolt-like symbols in Unicode, among them is U+2607 LIGHTNING (`☇`), though anything approaching realistic would require a special font with an actual lightning bolt glyph.